# Socket.IO y Angular has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular, typescript, socket.io

como van?. Lo que sucede es que cuando intento enviar un socket del lado del cliente (Angular) a el servidor (NodeJs) me sale el siguiente error:

[image: has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.]

este es mi código del lado del cliente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el codigo del servidor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero logren ayudarme y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Dejar imágenes con código por lo general se considera de mala calidad, lo mejor es copiar y pegar el código más relevante para tu pregunta

Comment: Puedes utilizar la librería cors.

Answer (score 1):

Seguramente el servidor HTTP está en un puerto diferente al que está el servidor de socket.io, por eso te sale ese error, porque se identifica como una petición a otro recurso diferente al actual, lee de CORS [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

En concreto para arreglarlo, puedes cambiar el header HTTP `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` (no lo vayas a poner en `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` por favor, checa cuál debería ser el valor según tu configuración), o también puedes "centralizar" ambos servicios al utilizar por ejemplo, un reverse proxy. De esta última forma se harían las peticiones de la aplicación y de socket.io a un mismo recurso, pero el reverse proxy redireccionaría las peticiones de la aplicación al servidor de la aplicación, y las de socket.io al servidor de socket.io.